# PHP PDO How to Display top SQL Count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, count

I have multiple "owners" that I want to count up together and display the top owner, I figured out the SQL statement, but Im not sure how to display that top count number in php?
To make things harder, the majority of the "owner" entries are blank, I want to exclude any blank entires and count them in their own statement, this is what I have so far:

```
$GMCB = $DBH->query('SELECT owner, count(owner) from griefprevention_claimdata group by owner ORDER BY count(owner) DESC LIMIT 1');

$GMCB->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $GMCB->fetch()) {
echo " - " . $row['owner'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this and use alias in SQL for count  of owner in the query. To exclude blank entries you can use is not null in where clause

```
 $GMCB = $DBH->query('SELECT owner, count(owner) as top_owner from 
 griefprevention_claimdata where owner is not null group by owner 
 ORDER BY count(owner) DESC LIMIT 1');

$GMCB->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $GMCB->fetch()) {
   echo  $row['owner '] ." - " . $row['top_owner '] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Aha! This works, apart from the "owner" data does not set to NULL its just empty field, Which means I get the top result of empty rows since they have many more rows than any other user, How could I fix this?

Comment: try this then instead of is not null use where owner !=''

Comment: Superb! I used where owner <> ""
And I can use it the other way around to pull only the blank ones too I presume!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
count(owner) AS owner_count
```

and then access it with

```
$row['owner_count']
```

You need a WHERE clause in your query like  WHERE owner is not null.